# Understanding Local Notification in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

I implemented a local notification test per this example https://www.codenameone.com/blog/local-notifications.html

I have the following two questions:

1) can I test local notifications from CN1 simulator. In the link above, I see a local notification test screenshot using the iPhone 6 simulator. Is there a way to force the app to run in background form the simulator in CN1?

2) If a local notification is sent when the app is running in foreground, I understand that the notification will not fire. Is the message lost in this case or is it queued somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can only test this on the device, it will work in the native simulator for iOS as you saw in the screeshot. You can run on the native iOS simulator using a Mac and [include source](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html).

The message would be lost if you fire in the foreground on iOS as it's the assumption that this is something you can notify within your app more effectively. You can determine if your app is in the foreground using the `Display.isMinimized()` method. In the foreground case you can use a tool like `ToastBar` to show a notification.